# Ставки на аукционе django

Tags: django

Делаю сайт аукцион на django.
Есть модель

```
class Lot(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'lot'

    lot_created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    lot_author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', default='1')
    lot_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    lot_description = models.TextField(default='',)
    lot_start_price = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=100)
    lot_last_bet = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.lot_name
```

при выводе в шаблон у каждого лота есть кнопка "ставка"

как сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку в поле lot_last_bet делалась запись (логин юзера,сделавшего ставку)?

или может есть другое решение?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user)

Если используете Django form, то во views.py

```
def lot(request):
    # Обработка POST метода
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LotForm(request.POST)
        # получаем пользователя, который заполнял форму
        user = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            # пока данные не сохраняем
            new_lot_object = form.save(commit=False)
            #записываем в lot_last_bet логин пользователя который заполнял форму
            new_lot_object.lot_last_bet = user.username
            new_lot_object.save()
            # перенаправляем на URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/lot/')

    form = LotForm()
    return render(request, 'lot.html', {'form': form})
```

Но я бы переделал поле модели

> lot_last_bet = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='', blank=True)

на:

```
lot_last_bet = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="lot_last_bet", verbose_name = "Кто сделал ставку")
```

Comment: спасибо, за подсказку. А откуда импортировать User подскажите?

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.models import User